# Running python with -c flag in C#

Tags: python, c#

I'm trying to run a python command from within a c# process. This command is a one-liner and not a script. But strangely enough when starting the python process with the `-c` flag, i.e. the command instead of script flag, I encounter some problems.

First an example of my code that runs a script and works fine:

```cs
using (Process python = new Process())
{
    python.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
    python.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-u C:\path\to\script.py";
    python.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    python.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    python.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    python.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    python.ErrorDataReceived += Print;
    python.OutputDataReceived += Print;

    python.Start();
    python.BeginErrorReadLine();
    python.BeginOutputReadLine();
    python.WaitForExit();
}

static void Print(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

With the following script as an example:

```py
import time

for i in range(5):
    print("Hello World " + str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

The output is retrieved as it is created (not waiting until the process is finished):

```
Hello World 0
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
Hello World 3
Hello World 4
null
null
```

Then, if I change the StartInfo.Argument to `"-uc 'print(1)'"`, the only two output lines I get are the null values at the end, but the `1` you would expect to retrieve from the print statement is missing:

```
null
null
```

And lastly, if I add any space to the executing command (such as `"-uc 'print(1); print(2)'"`), I get an EOL message on StdErr:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    'print(1);
              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
null
null
```

And for completeness; running that from the command line works just fine:

```
$> python -uc 'print(1); print(2)'
1
2
```

Any clues how to solve both these problems?

Comment: The official examples seem to use double quotes to combine arguments, maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try this. It solved both problems... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use double quotes on the arguments in order to get it to be read correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).